# How do delete single row in pivot table with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, detach

I want to delete a single row of data in my pivot table. I don't get any error but when try to click on the button. It did not redirect me to anywhere so the delete function is not performed.

[image: pivot table]

In the picture above I want to delete the highlighted id for `user_id = 3`
My scenario is that the user suddenly can't make it to `even_id = 6` so the user wants to delete/unjoined the event.

`route`

```
Route::get('/user/event/{event}', 'HomeController@destroy')->name('user.event.destroy');
```

`blade`

```
@foreach ($events as $event)
    <tr>
       <td>{{$loop->index +1 }}</td>
       <td>{{$event->event_name}}</td>
       <td>{{$event->event_date}}</td>
       <td>
        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('user.event.destroy',$event)}}">
          @csrf 
          @method('DELETE')
           <a class="btn btn-danger">Unjoined!</a> 
         </form>
         </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

`controller`

```
public function storeEventUser(Request $request)
    {
       $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
     //how I storing my pivot data (just to show if anyone asking)
      $user->events()->syncWithoutDetaching([$request->event_id]);
    }


 public function destroy($event)
    {
        $event= Event::findOrFail($event_id);
        $user->events()->detach($event);
        return redirect()->back()->with('success','Deleted.');
    }
```

`Event model`

```
 public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'event_user','event_id','user_id');
    }
```

`user model`

```
public function events()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Event::class,'event_user','user_id','event_id');
    }
```

Comment: did you try your code? is there a particular thing you need clarified?

Comment: Yes. I forgot to mention my problem. Updated it.

Comment: that `a` (anchor) does not submit the form

Comment: Your web.php route is a get method, not a post or delete

Comment: `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Unjoined!</button > `

Comment: @lagbox  if that so how do I fix that?

Comment: @Cameron so I need to change the `get` into `post`?

Comment: you would have to change it to `delete` since that is the method you are spoofing in your form

Comment: it looks like you are using @method('DELETE') so I would use Route::delete

Comment: oh silly me thank you!. Finally I do get error now `Undefined variable: event_id`

Comment: It would be `Event::findOrFail($event);`

Comment: @sta Do I have to do the same things to $user to? since it also undefined variable?

Comment: @lagbox I saw your explanation below, how do fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am adjusting your controller method to use Route Model Binding for simplicity:

```
public function destroy(Event $event)
{
    Auth::user()->events()->detach($event);
    // or from the other side of the relationship
    // $event->users()->detach(Auth::user());

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Deleted.');
}
```

As stated in the comments you need to adjust your route to `Route::delete` if you want to use the `DELETE` HTTP method that your form is spoofing via the `@method('DELETE')` blade directive.

**Side note:**

`Auth::user()` returns a `User` instance so you don't need to query for it again, in your `storeEventUser` method:

```
$user = Auth::user();
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I learn lot of things today from you and others too. I need to learn more for this. Thank you :)

Comment: there is a lot going on, just take it slow and try to understand the context of the things you are doing as best as possible :)